# Plotting cosine similarities in 3d space from word embeddings

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec, normalization, cosine-distance

I'm working on a project in which I want to estimate biases from a large corpus of newspaper articles using word2vec. Following [this](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0003122419877135) and [this](https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.aal4230) paper, biases are calculated by constructing dimension x as a normalized vector derived from the embeddings of antonym word pairs (say, rich - poor). Next, I project the normalized embeddings for different groups (say, different professions) on that axis by matrix multuplication. So what I end up with are cosine similarity scores ranging from -1 to 1 (also see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/146271) answer).

Now my idea was to plot the various groups in a 3d space with dimensions x, y, z. Can I just plot the cosine scores in a 3d geometric space? Or am I then violating some mathematical principle?

So far I've run some tests and the output seem valid from a qualitative perspective (as in: it confirms my own biases).